# how can I open a link in a webView (on a local file) in external browser?

Tags: webview

I have a WebView that I opened a local file from asset on it.

then, when I clik on a link for opennig another local file from asset, unfortunately, the new file replace, and does not open in the external browser.

I want the second file is opened in the external browser.

how can I do that.

---

edit :

I have a html file in asset named list.html. in this html file there are 20 links that refer to 20 html files in the assets. I want to open the list.html file in my WebView. then, when I click on 20 links in this file, links will be opened in external browser, not replace the list.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new activity and invoke the web browser application and pass the url to it.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```

this might help, I haven't test it.

Comment: thank for reply. my WebView is in a fragmant, and also my first file must be opened in WebView.

Comment: my question is that : how can the second file be opened in external browser.

your code opens the first file in external browser.

Comment: dude you should set the logic yourself, I don't know what is your code and logic and what you are trying to do. One possible solution could be using a bool variable and call it flag. for example set the flag to false when you initiate the class. So if is false that means is the first file so open it in a webview and then set the flag true. So the second round check if the flag is true and if it is true then open it in external webview and again set back the flag to false.

Comment: I have a html file in asset named list.html. in this html file there are 20 links that refer to 20 html files in the assets. I want to open the list.html file in my WebView. then, when I click on 20 links in this file, links will be opened in external browser, not replace the list.html file.

Comment: well the way you are going this really strange if you have something like that why don't you create the list in listview? if you don't know how follow this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html  however if you really want to use your web knowledge to develop an app why don't you use phonegap http://phonegap.com/ and use only javascript and html then you can even compile your code into both Androd and iPhone.

Comment: thank you for your reply.I am a beginner in android. I mentioned list.html as an example for you. in fact, list.html is a big html file that there is 20 links in it, that refer to 20 articles with html format in assets. I know how to build a listview. but my links must be in list.html. i will go to phonegap.com.